# how to update column value from another dict table in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables like the following:

**Table 1: Item List**

```
itemName, ...
,A1.xxx, ...
,A1.xxx, ...
,A2.xxx, ...
,C3.xxx, ...
NA,B2.xxx, ...
```

**Table 2: Item Code/Name**

```
itemCode, itemName
A1, Pen
A1, Pen
A2, Pencil
C3, Milk
B2, iPad
```

What I'm going to do is to update the **itemName** column in table 1 with the **itemName** value in table 2. Note that the **itemCode** in table 2 is a substring of the **itemName** in table 1. How can I do that? I'm using sql server.

Thanks!

Comment: Use a foreign key concept or a trigger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be possible to do something like this - I have not tested it though.

```
UPDATE t1 SET
itemName = t2.itemName
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.itemCode = 
SUBSTRING(t1.itemName, 
    CHARINDEX(',', t1.itemName)+1, 
    (
        (CHARINDEX(',', t1.itemName)+1) - CHARINDEX('.', t1.itemName)
    )
)
```